# React native - Which is the best way to compress video before upload to server?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, ffmpeg, video-processing

We are using ffmpeg library (https://github.com/tanersener/react-native-ffmpeg) but with large videos this task is taking too long time, up to 4 minutes or more in some cases.

The ffmpeg command we are using is:
`ffmpeg -y -i {inputVideo.mp4} -c:v libx264 -crf 24 -preset ultrafast -vf scale=-2:720,format=yuv420p -movflags +faststart {outputVideo.mp4}`

We want to have a quickly (and perfomant) compression so the user experience will not be affected

Answer (score 2):

[This Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-compressor)

This works in the background of the app too. So when you close the app, it should continue compression. Here's an example on how I use it:

Import the Methods

```js
import {
  Video as VideoCompress,
  Image as ImageCompress,
} from "react-native-compressor";
```

Compress either video or image

```js
if (media.type === "image") {
  await ImageCompress.compress(
    media.uri,
    {
      compressionMethod: "auto",
    },
    (progress) => {
      console.log({ compression: progress });
    }
  ).then(async (compressedFileUrl) => {
  // do something with compressed image file
  });
}
      
if (media.type === "video") {
  await VideoCompress.compress(
    media.uri,
    {
      compressionMethod: "auto",
    },
    (progress) => {
      console.log({ compression: progress });
    }
  ).then(async (compressedFileUrl) => {
  // do something with compressed video file
  });
}
```

Comment: Is this actually compressing? I couldn’t see the size being reduced.

Comment: @Anitta you need to set minimum size the file must be to compress using minimumFileSizeForCompress as shown in the docs. Defaults to 16mb so if a file is smaller than this, it won't compress.

Comment: please help afetr installing react-native-compressor-1.6.1 with react-native-0.70.6 it gives error FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-compressor:compileDebugAidl'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':react-native-compressor:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve io.github.lizhangqu:coreprogress:1.0.2.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-compressor
      > Skipped due to earlier error
      > Skipped due to earlier error

Answer (score 0):

Try [this library](https://github.com/classapp/react-native-video-helper) and see if it works better for you.

note: this library does not accept as much option as ffmpeg. but also has way less size.